# How to map constants to strings

Tags: typescript

I have a `type` definition like this

```
type Foo = {
    bold?: boolean,
    italic?: boolean,
    color: Colors <- this is the problem
}
```

`Color` has got to be one of these values

```
const col1= '#C62828'
const col2= '#01579B'
const col3 = '#E65100'
```

I thought I make an `enum` out of it

```
enum Colors {
    red: col1,
    blue: col2,
    orange: col3,
}
```

But this gives me

> Only numeric enums can have computed members, but this expression has type '"#C62828"'. If you do not need exhaustiveness checks, consider using an object literal instead.
> ...

And then highlighlting `col1`, `col2`, `col3`.

What is the best way to create a mapping like this, so that I can use as a `type` for `color`? I want to make sure that

1. only colors defined via `col1`, `col2`, `col3` are allowed to passed and
2. be able to use the actual value (i.e. `#C62828`) of the passed Color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a constant with key value pairs for the colors.
Like:

```
const col1 = '#C62828'
const col2 = '#01579B'
const col3 = '#E65100'

const COLORS = {
    RED: col1,
    BLUE: col2,
    ORANGE: col3,
} as const // as const to type the values as (ex: '#C62828') instead of `string`.
```

For getting the values as types of the `COLORS` object use this type:

```
type Colors = typeof COLORS[keyof typeof COLORS] // "#C62828" | "#01579B" | "#E65100"
```

Now can implement the type to an Object and will only allow the values added to the `COLORS` constant.

```
type Foo = {
    bold?: boolean,
    italic?: boolean,
    color: Colors
}

const implementedFoo: Foo = {
    color: "#01579B"
}

const implementedFoo2: Foo = {
    color: COLORS.BLUE
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBKA2BGGBeGByAxAYQGwCYAOI9AWAChRJYF9UNMAGRAVgHYBOAITMvGjgh4AZnpYAorhaJGjXhSoDsAeQAyygEoBlegG8KMQzA3iAIgC5BSADQGjXVQFVxl2rfJGYmgIIA5AOIuVsLuAL4wAIYQgtQwAPRxkdGKsFAgMFAAngAOAKYZABb5AG4R8ACuudFRMAAUuQAellh4RCQAlDAAlhBgULkRACYwIABmMNAATl1gAOYAdBQUWXkw2EIgk9FoK7lja2qaWgDaANa5mfu7%20yrq2gC6S%20S7MABiIOlo%20h5GAEZCgwA-JZ-kIBmB3J4ulAyl1gMCYKD4ODIUYEJtLOt4JsIBRQk8Ut0ALbZZFE3J9XKDd4gSw0vR2QzoyaWABETFYnC4rLxBP4sC6JLJFP61I%20%20DpHwZPyZGxZBzuWnmDmcvPIFCAA)